# How to search for multiple file extensions from shell script

Tags: bash, sed, grep

```
for file in "$1"/*

 do

    if [ ! -d "${file}" ] ; then

   if [[ $file == *.c ]]

    then
blah

blah
```

Above code traverses all the .c files in a directory and does some action.I want to include .cpp,.h,.cc files as well.How can I check multiple file extensions in the same if condition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine conditions using boolean operators :

```
if [[ "$file" == *.c ]] || [[ "$file" == *.cpp ]] || [[ "$file" == *.h ]] || [[ "$file" == *.cc ]]; then
    #...
fi
```

Another alternative would be to use a regex :

```
if [[ "$file" =~ \.(c|cpp|h|cc)$ ]]; then
    #...
fi
```

Comment: I am interested in second one,but I am getting the syntax error while running from my script.

Comment: ./test_sed.sh: line 20: syntax error in conditional expression
./test_sed.sh: line 20: syntax error near `\.('
./test_sed.sh: line 20: `      if [[ "$file" = ~ \.(c|cpp|h|cc)$ ]] '

Comment: @RakeshTalari if I believe your comment you've got a space between `=` and `~` which you should remove (`=~`  is the regex match operator)

Comment: Got it now,I had put space after = while lead error.Now working fine.Thanks

Comment: Regex alternative fails : Syntax error around "(" with MacOsX Bash 3.2.57

Answer (score 5):

Using extended patterns,

```
# Only necessary prior to bash 4.1; since then,
# extglob is temporarily turn on for the pattern argument to !=
# and =/== inside [[ ... ]]
shopt -s extglob nullglob

for file in "$1"/*; do
    if [[ -f $file && $file = *.@(c|cc|cpp|h) ]]; then
        ...
    fi
done
```

The extended pattern can also be to generate the file list; in that case, you *definitely* need the `shopt` command:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for file in "$1"/*.@(c|cc|cpp|h); do
    ...
done
```

Comment: chepner, ++. Do you remember the exact release? (too tired to check the source) :/

Comment: Looks like that was added in 4.1 (see https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES, item 3s)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just iterate over selected file extensions?

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ${1}/*.[ch] ${1}/*.cc ${1}/*.cpp; do
    if [ -f $file ]; then
        # action for the file
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question if other files are ignored inside the loop, but this is certainly more efficient if they are. Let the shell's internal pattern matcher filter out the other files instead of explicitly checking them in the loop.

Comment: Note that it is important to check that the results of the `for` are indeed files, because unless the `nullglob` shell option has been set, a pattern which does not correspond to any file will be iterated over as a string. Also, the sequence could be shortened to `for file in $1/*.{c,h,cc,cpp}; do...`